# how long to replicate adprep /forestprep to second domain controller?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-sbs-2003, schema

i updated our sbs 2003 server using adprep /forestprep
waited about 1/2hr and checked the second DC 's usn number, the sbs 2003 is 8875 and the usn for the second DC is 4410?

can i force the second DC to check in with the sbs 2003 to get updated schema? or what is the default period that the other DC's check in with the sbs 2003 box holding the fsmo roles?

thanks.gd

Comment: the reason i am updating the schemas is that i need to add a third DC to to mix and phase out the old backup DC. i just want to make sure that nothgin will get messed up since the second DC has the lower lower lower USN number. i checked this value under the aduc, system, windows2003updates, right click and check teh object tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to the AD schema replicate to other DCs the same way as any other update. If the servers are in the same AD site the replication will begin within 5 minutes of the change. If the servers are in different AD sites then the replication schedule on the site link will determine the duration of the delay before tart of repliation.

I'd recommend installing "REPLMON" from the "Windows Support Tools" (in the "\SUPPORT" folder of the Windows Server CD) so that you can get a graphical view of the replication topology and the last replication status for each partition of the AD. You can force replication from REPLMON the same as you can from AD Sites and Services, but you get more feedback from REPLMON.

The USNs you're looking at don't have to do with replication of the schema. Those are the update sequence numbers on the given objects you're looking at. You want to look at the replication status of the Schema / Configuration partition itself.

Comment: ok thanks, i did the force replication from the gui side before i posted this question but again was thrown off on the usn numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Sites and Services, find your target server in the container and then expand to display the NTDS settings object.
2. Click the “NTDS Settings” option.
3. In the pane you should see a list of the replication connections.
4. Right click the connection object and click “Replicate Now”.

Comment: already did this, so evan is probably right that i am misunderstandingn something i read on teh internet about USN numbers.